# Ecommerce Datafeed

Tags: excel, csv, e-commerce, datafeed

I'm trying to build a e-commerce site for a client and it isn't quite as straightforward as I had hoped.  I am using Magento Community and my client has a wholesaler who provides a data feed (over 5000 products).  In order to make this data feed compliant with Magento (and its attributes), I have edited some column headings in Excel and successfully uploaded as a CSV file.

My issue is that the wholesaler regularly renews the data feed automatically.  When this happens, I am assuming my tweaking of the spreadsheet will be overruled, making my now Magento compatible CSV file useless again.

My question then is how can I make the wholesaler data feed compliant with my revised version so I don't have to continually rename elements?  Is this possible?

I apologise if this sounds very stupid but I am more seasoned to static website builds.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your webserver have access to the newly produced updated automatic data feed ?

IF so, just fetch the feed, modifty it to be complaint with the magento data feed then find the magento 'processfeed' or whatever function, and run it against the file ?

If your webserver cannot automatically fetch the file, can the pc making the feed automatically post the data to the webserver ?

IF neither are possible so far, then there will always be a manual person who has to 'reupload the feed'.. in which case, just make a simple page for them, 'Upload feed', or modify the magento page, and let them upload their standard feed, reformat it, then process the reformatted feed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a script to transform wholesaler data feed into magento format so you do not need to rename manually every time.